vite public compile confusion
const imageList = [
    "Wildcard.png",
    "Diamonds.png",
    "Hearts.png",
    "Spades.png",
    "Clubs.png"
].map((v) => new URL(`/img/${v}`, import.meta.url).href);

Why is this not equivalent to this?
The first one yields /example-project/assets/undefined
The second one yields the correct one /example-project/img/Wildcard.png
const imageList = [
    new URL("/img/Wildcard.png", import.meta.url).href,
    new URL("/img/Diamonds.png", import.meta.url).href,
    new URL("/img/Hearts.png", import.meta.url).href,
    new URL("/img/Spades.png", import.meta.url).href,
    new URL("/img/Clubs.png", import.meta.url).href,
];

In some rare cases, the first one can yields /src/components/undefined with the use of a function that behaves almost exactly like that map callback but instead of an arrow function it is an actual function declaration. The base on vite.config.js is set correctly to the repo name for Github-Pages deployment.
I don't know if I'm a bit misguided on where static assets lived, or some side-effects I forgot to take a count of, or **there's something seriously wrong with how I compile / build the app with Vite. **
I am thoroughly confused and wished to gain some more insight on this.

This reminds me of a Webpack issue I had related to Webworkers where a particular syntax is expected. The relevant info is here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/. I don't know if this is is fact a similar issue, but the fact that using a variable breaks things feels similar.

It's unclear how "/src/components/undefined" is related to "/img". "In some rare cases" - which ones?

@EstusFlask I have no idea why it returns the components path but this is what I do
function getImagePath(name) {
    return new URL(name, import.meta.url).href
}

const imageList = [
    "/img/Wildcard.png",
    "/img/Diamonds.png",
    "/img/Hearts.png",
    "/img/Spades.png",
    "/img/Clubs.png",
].map(getImagePath);

Practically identical with the other map callback but produces different result
